# Partial Page updates and Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm new to web design and I have a question about how to best organise and layout my code.

I'm writing a web application which has a main layout with a tree view down the left hand side and a navigation menu across the top of the page. The of the menu and tree doesn't change much.

Then to the right of the navigation tree and below the navigation menu I have my main display area ( for a lack of better words).  This content is very dynamic.

At the moment I'm using Jquery's $.get function and .html to call my backend server which based on the param's passed returns the html to place in this main display area.

i.e something like this below.

```
(".getUser").click(function(){
$.get('/getUser'), {username: $(this).attr("id"), role: 'user'},
  function (data) {
        // put html into the section
        $("div#displaycontent").html(data);
    })
});
```

So my questions are

1) Is this an acceptable way to update just the main display area?

2) The updated display area may have edit boxes' and buttons etc… which is then bound to other jquery code. Should that jquery code already be put at the bottom of my main HTML page or should I just include the script in my 'data' returned from my .get function with the rest of the HTML? returning it as part of the 'data' with my new HTML works but I'm not sure if thats a bad way to do things.

Comment: If you use event delegation for those elements, it'd probably be better

Comment: Yes, that would be an acceptable would. Regarding your second question: if your edit boxes, buttons etc. are only relevant for the currently loaded "page" (loaded content), make sure it is only when the associated content loads. Make sure that you unbind controls on content change otherwise you'd get duplicate event listeners and possibly odd page behavior.

Comment: Hi SaschaM78, in regards to unbinding the controls, I'm not sure how this all works in the background. For instance when I make my call to .html(data) I am inserting the new html controls and associated Javascript. When the user ,for instance, selects another menu item, that HTML and Javascript is 'replaced' by the next call to .html(data). Is that enough to effectively unbind it? I have many different menu options, all of which will return a different set of HTML,controls and javascript. Many thanks.